# Is it possible to Install Windows 8 Server(Beta) on a existing EC2 AMI?

Tags: amazon-ec2

I want to try out this OS,so I am trying to understand how to do this.

Should I do inplace upgrade of a 2008 AMI and burn as a custom AMI?

or

Create a Virtual Image on Laptop and upload a AMI package to EC2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently it's possible if you perform an in-place upgrade on a Windows Server 2008 R2 instance.